# How to use helmfile

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, kubectl, helmfile, kubernetes-helm

*helmfile* was released recently and we would like to adopt it. 
https://github.com/roboll/helmfile

**my simple helmfile:**

```
vim charts.yaml

...
releases:
  # Published chart example
  - name: prometheus_no_rbac                            # name of this release
    namespace: prometheus                       # target namespace
    chart: stable/prometheus     # the chart being installed to create this release, referenced by `repository/chart` syntax
    #values: [ vault.yaml ]                 # value files (--values)
    set:                                   # values (--set)
      - name: rbac.create
        value: false
...
wq!
```

**When I run:**

```
./helmfile -f charts.yaml
NAME:
   helmfile -

USAGE:
   helmfile [global options] command [command options] [arguments...]

VERSION:
   v0.8

COMMANDS:
     repos   sync repositories from state file (helm repo add && helm repo update)
     charts  sync charts from state file (helm repo upgrade --install)
     diff    diff charts from state file against env (helm diff)
     sync    sync all resources from state file (repos && charts)
     delete  delete charts from state file (helm delete)

GLOBAL OPTIONS:
   --file FILE, -f FILE  load config from FILE (default: "charts.yaml")
   --quiet, -q           silence output
   --kube-context value  Set kubectl context. Uses current context by default
   --help, -h            show help
   --version, -v         print the version
```

I just wanted to rewrite this piece of **working code**:

```
helm install stable/prometheus --name prom --set rbac.create=false --namespace=prometheus
```

Comment: We have a comprehensive write up on using `helmfile` here (with examples): https://docs.cloudposse.com/tools/helmfile/

Also, I recommend checking out their newest addition: `helmfile.d` which allows you to decompose a helmfile into smaller, ordered files.

Comment: We have published our library of helmfiles here: https://github.com/cloudposse/helmfiles

Examples include: kube2iam, kiam, external-dns, kube-lego, cert-manager, chartmuseum, nginx-ingress, prometheus-operator, kube-prometheus, grafana, datalog, fluentd-datadog-logs, fluentd-elasticsearch-logs, heapster, kubernetes dashboard, portal, kibana

Answer (score 4):

Working example **hemlfile** of usage.

```
cat helmfile.yaml

context: <my_context> # not mandatory I guess

releases:
  # Published chart example
  - name: promnorbacxubuntu         # name of this release
    namespace: prometheus              # target namespace
    chart: stable/prometheus             # the chart being installed to create this release, referenced by `repository/chart` syntax
    set:                                   # values (--set)
      - name: rbac.create
        value: false
```

**Usage**:

`./helmfile -f hemlfile.yaml sync`

The problem was that they have released a new version **v0.10**
https://github.com/roboll/helmfile/releases/tag/v0.10

**Github Issue**: https://github.com/roboll/helmfile/issues/55#issuecomment-373714894

I have tested it in following envs.:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Centos 7.3
- windows 10 via cygwin with minikube + Virtualbox

Enjoy!